# Input html tag not parsing properly in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING 59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060013/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-59)

I have a database with names that I would like displayed in the form of a table with checkboxes.  Everything works until I try to place the html  tag into my php code.  When I put the input tag in it gives me the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

I can't see where I would put a comma or semi colon.

```
<form>
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
    $user_name = "a1611480_akaash";
    $pwd = "****";
    $database_name = "a1611480_akaash";
    $db = mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);

    mysql_select_db($database_name);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Sort");

    $var = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $var[] = $row['name'];
    }

    $unique = array_unique($var);

    foreach ($unique as $value) {

        echo "<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="$value" /> </p>\n";
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
echo "<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="$value" /> </p>\n"
```

with this:

```
echo <<<EOD
<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="$value" /> </p>
EOD;
```

... This uses [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which easily bypasses most of your quotation issues. However, it comes with an important caveat: the line `EOD;` **must not** be indented and there cannot be anything else on that line (such as trailing spaces).

Comment: I fricken *love* heredoc, +1. Would be nice to point out to op rules around the closing tag.  ;)

Comment: @Madbreaks Agreed. Saves SO much time.

Answer (score 2):

On your echo line, the entire thing must be surrounded by double quotes. You open the double quotes before checkbox so it is seeing *checkbox* as an unknown PHP call. Use a combination of single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

change this line.. u have to escape doublequotes

```
echo "<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"name\" value=\"$value\" /> </p>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "echo" line with

```
echo "<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type='checkbox' name='name' value='$value' /> </p>\n";
```

Because you use double quotes as a string delimiter and also for the checkbox itself, it kinda breaks out of the php string.

Comment: Ugh, single quotes for HTML attributes?

Comment: Yup, i don't see a problem there?! As especially HTML5 gives you the freedom to do almost whatever you want with your attributes, it comes down to personal belief I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes, or perhaps use heredoc syntax.  See below for a couple of examples where you're breaking your PHP code:

```
echo "<p class = Body_text><label>$value</label> <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="$value" /> </p>\n";
                                                            ^^^      ^^^
```

Comment: Ok, yeah I see.  Thanks a lot, I'm fairly new to php.